# Cannot archive an iOS project

Tags: ios, app-store, archive

Seems like there is some kind of problem with png images (icon and default screenshots). Tried to re-save them in PhotoShop, copy-paste them. It sometimes changes the number of images, but they are still there.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

## 1

> CopyPNGFile
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dotLang-hfjdkwzpxfuyaibhmihjxdyzyzqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/dotLang/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dotlang.app/Default@2x.png"
>   "dotLang/Default@2x.png"
>       cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/newCode 2 3 2 2 2 2/dotLang"
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   -compress "" "/Users/admin/Desktop/newCode 2 3 2 2 2 2/dotLang/dotLang/Default@2x.png"
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dotLang-hfjdkwzpxfuyaibhmihjxdyzyzqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/dotLang/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dotlang.app/Default@2x.png"
>
> 䏰\216\346\217ﮚ@A\346\217\320Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate
>   failure

## 2

> CopyPNGFile
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dotLang-hfjdkwzpxfuyaibhmihjxdyzyzqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/dotLang/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dotlang.app/Default-568h@2x.png"
>   "dotLang/Default-568h@2x.png"
>       cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/newCode 2 3 2 2 2 2/dotLang"
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   -compress "" "/Users/admin/Desktop/newCode 2 3 2 2 2 2/dotLang/dotLang/Default-568h@2x.png"
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dotLang-hfjdkwzpxfuyaibhmihjxdyzyzqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/dotLang/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dotlang.app/Default-568h@2x.png"
>
> 台~\347\217ﮚ@1\347\217\320Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate
>   failure

## 3

> CopyPNGFile
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dotLang-hfjdkwzpxfuyaibhmihjxdyzyzqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/dotLang/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dotlang.app/Default-568h@2x.png"
>   "Default-568h@2x.png"
>       cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/newCode 2 3 2 2 2 2/dotLang"
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   -compress "" "/Users/admin/Desktop/newCode 2 3 2 2 2 2/dotLang/Default-568h@2x.png"
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dotLang-hfjdkwzpxfuyaibhmihjxdyzyzqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/dotLang/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dotlang.app/Default-568h@2x.png"
>
> Ᏸ\376\343\217ﮚ@\261\343\217\320Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate
>   failure

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking over icon in Xcode in the summary screen then delete any previous icons, clean rebuild.